# how to ceate folders in ADLS gen2 by reading a csv file(particular column) stored in adls gen2 in Databrciks

Tags: python, csv, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I need help in to ceate folders in ADLS gen2 by reading a csv file(particular column) stored in adls gen2 in Databrciks.
I am able to read csv file but not able to create folders in gen2 using databrciks.

I tried reading csv file using account key and SAS token,which i am able to read but not able to craete folders using mount folder in gen2.

Can someone please help on coding part like creating python code to create folders in gen2 using mount point.

`dbutils.fs.mount( source = 'path', mount_point = '/mnt/...', extra_configs = {path,accountkey})`

Answer (score 0):

To create a directory, you can either use Databricks's `dbutils` or use python's `os` library.

- You can create directory in your mount folder with `dbutils` in the following way.

```
dbutils.fs.mkdirs("/mnt/repro/folder1")
```

- To create new folder using Python, import `os` library and then use `os.mkdir`.

```
import os
os.mkdir("/dbfs/mnt/repro/folder2")
```

- You can check if the folders are created or not using `dbutils.fs.ls`.

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/repro")
```

[image]

**NOTE:** You can also create sub-directories using `dbutils` but not with python's os library.

Comment: Thank you.But can you plaese help me to create folders inside parent folder using dbutils commnad as i need to create directory in gen2 reading csv file which contains path like \a\b\c\d\e in one column. below code not helping                                                                                                Result = "/mnt/blobc123/"
dataCollect = df.collect()
for row in dataCollect:
    print(row['_c1'])
#dataCollect=df.rdd.toLocalIterator()
for row in dataCollect:
    value = (row["_c1"])
    basedir= Result
    dbutils.fs.mkdirs(os.path.join(basedir,value))

Comment: I am bale to create hierrcal folder.The mistake i was doing is missing / before path same it shoud be "\a\b\c\d\e i was giving "a\b\c\d\e .

Comment: Please consider accepting it as an answer so it might help other community members.